# AngularJS : What is a factory?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-factory

I've been doing a lot of work on `Angular.js` and overall I find it to be an interesting and powerful framework.

I know there have been a lot of discussions on Services vs. Factories vs. Providers vs. Values, but I am still pretty confused about what a `Factory` is.

Factory has been defined in other StackOverflow discussions as the following:

*Factories*

Syntax: `module.factory( 'factoryName', function );` Result: When declaring factoryName as an injectable argument you will be provided with the value that is returned by invoking the function reference passed to module.factory.

I find this explanation to be very difficult to grasp and it doesn't increase my understanding of what a factory is.

Would anyone have any explanations or real life examples to share about what exactly a `Factory` is and why you should use it in lieu of a `Service`, `Provider`, or other?

#### Update

A `service` *holds a reference* to any **object**.

A `factory` *is a function* which returns any **object**

A `provider` *is a function* which returns any **function**

-*phew*-

Comment: I would not say this is a duplicate of that question, rather I read that question before asking this one as its answer on `Factories` (quoted above) was a little confusing. Some of the answers below reduce `Factories` to something even I can make sense of

Comment: This question has more upvotes than the one it "duplicates", perhaps things should be the other way around?

Comment: This [link](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Dependency-Injection) explains it well.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

From what I understand they are all pretty much the same. The major differences are their complexities. Providers are configurable at runtime, factories are a little more robust, and services are the simplest form.

Check out this question [AngularJS: Service vs provider vs factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666048/angular-js-service-vs-provide-vs-factory)

Also this [gist](https://gist.github.com/Mithrandir0x/3639232) may be helpful in understanding the subtle differences.

Source: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/hVrkvaHGOfc

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pkozlowski_opensource/PxdSP/14/

author: **Pawel Kozlowski**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

//service style, probably the simplest one
myApp.service('helloWorldFromService', function() {
    this.sayHello = function() {
        return "Hello, World!";
    };
});

//factory style, more involved but more sophisticated
myApp.factory('helloWorldFromFactory', function() {
    return {
        sayHello: function() {
            return "Hello, World!";
        }
    };
});

//provider style, full blown, configurable version     
myApp.provider('helloWorld', function() {
    // In the provider function, you cannot inject any
    // service or factory. This can only be done at the
    // "$get" method.

    this.name = 'Default';

    this.$get = function() {
        var name = this.name;
        return {
            sayHello: function() {
                return "Hello, " + name + "!";
            }
        };
    };

    this.setName = function(name) {
        this.name = name;
    };
});

//hey, we can configure a provider!            
myApp.config(function(helloWorldProvider){
    helloWorldProvider.setName('World');
});


function MyCtrl($scope, helloWorld, helloWorldFromFactory, helloWorldFromService) {

    $scope.hellos = [
        helloWorld.sayHello(),
        helloWorldFromFactory.sayHello(),
        helloWorldFromService.sayHello()];
}​
```

Comment: So one way of looking at them, is that in order of complexity they go `Provider > Factory > Service > Value` ?

Comment: Thats one way to look at it, another would be to think of Factory and Service as abstractions of Provider. Someone correct me if I am wrong but Factory and Service use Provider under the hood. Which is why provide is the "Closest to the metal" version. I believe Value is a way to define constants that can then be used application wide.

Answer (score 18):

One major difference I see is that you can run custom code in the factory. But, in a service, only object creation happens.

```
myJs.factory('Factory', function() {

    //Write custom code here

    return {
            Hello: function() {
            return "Hello, World!"
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: you can also run custom code in a service constructor function, can't you? nobody said inside a constructor function, you can't run other code

Answer (score 10):

My two cents on this topic. I am a very very newbie and just into  understanding Angular JS and this was one of the things that confused me a lot and hence I studied it in somewhat detail. I have been making notes for giving interviews and this may be useful to others.

- service and factory do the same things in different ways
- both are injectibles
- for most things use factory syntax
- easier to understand
- nowadays with es6 "service" is done since it converts to es6 classes better
- its essentially abstracting away business logic from the controller
- if you use biz logic with controllers then you can only use with controllers
- controller is for putting data on scope not processing lengthy biz logic
- so what happens in above scenario is that complex biz logic is tied up into controllers. Not for processing data. So put bits and pieces of it into services or factory. So your code is lean and modular.
- services are singletons

Answer (score 0):

Services are mostly objects in which you describe the constructor class of the object. Somewhere deep within the framework, the Object.create() function is called and then you can use a service by calling its object and methods using a controller. Factory, on the other hand, doesn't create an object by default and hence requires you to return the entire object location once you're done defining all the attributes and methods.