# AngularJS advice on converting Factory to Provider?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-factory, angularjs-provider

I need to inject content from a Factory into a Config but I know this isn't possible and is only possible if I use a provider instead,  so please can anyone advise how to convert my factory into a Provider?

```
var templateApp = angular.module('templateApp', ['ngMaterial', 'ngRoute']);

templateApp.factory('pageFactory', function () {

    var pages = [
                {icon: 'assessment', name: 'Overview', route: '/partial1', template: 'View1.html'},
                {icon: 'assignment', name: 'Dashboard', route: '/partial2', template: 'View2.html'}
        ];

    var factory = {};
    factory.getPages = function(){
        return pages;
    }

    return factory;
});
```

Many thanks

Dom

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS : What is a factory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596569/angularjs-what-is-a-factory) Look at the answers, that might explain what you need to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS: Service vs provider vs factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666048/angularjs-service-vs-provider-vs-factory). My [favorite answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33805462/5535245) has a nice picture of the relationship.

Comment: what do you want to expose during config phase?