# What is a Factory method in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I know there have been a lot of discussions on Services vs. Factories vs. Providers vs. Values, but I am still pretty confused about what a Factory is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS : What is a factory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596569/angularjs-what-is-a-factory)

Comment: You tagged this question as angular but mentioned AngularJS in the title. Which of the two is it about? But it is maybe too broad as well.